# What is the meaning of 'IN' in new YouTube logo previously it used to be 'TM'?

Tags: youtube

Go to youtube website see its logo in top left corner. 'IN' is shown as superscript to logo. I tried searching on Google and Wikipedia but couldn't find any information.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Its not exactly clear what you are talking about.  Can you provide a screenshot of the logo in question.  Just link to the image and somebody will add it to your question.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be *indian* would you?

Comment: You can find the image at: http://i.imgur.com/VnaqKm6.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your country setting is set to India. (Country settings can be independent from your physical location. I'm physically in US now but my country setting is Japan, and I see "JP" next to the logo.)

Scroll to the bottom of the site and you will see a menu like this:
[image: Youtube menu at bottom]

In your case, the country must be set to India. If you don't want it to be, change that to worldwide.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It refers to country specific YouTube sites. I’m in Singapore, so it says SG.

Comment: I am in USA but still it is showing me that.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube India.

http://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1&gl=IN

“IN” means country specific YouTube for India, and could have country specific content.

Comment: I am in USA but still it is showing me that

Comment: I am guessing you have taken your laptop from India to there, your browser and/or OS is set with Indian settings/time zone. either your browser or OS is detecting that and directing you to the default country specific YouTube site. I could further guess your using chrome browser (or even firefox perhaps) and your google account is set for India.